# VMWare workstation: "not enough physical memory available to start this VM" when installing Linux as guest OS

Tags: vmware-workstation

I installed VMWare workstation on my laptop,  which has Windows 8 running on it. I got VMWare installed, after which I tried to install Red hat Linux as a guest OS.

But I get an error stating "not enough physical memory available to start this VM."

I tried allocating all more resources to get Linux installed and overcome the above error:

RAM - 2GB
DISK - 20GB

but still get the same error.

Comment: How much memory does your laptop have? Do you have other processes running on the host (Windows 8) that are taking up a lot of memory? Remember that Windows requires memory too, so even if your laptop has 2 GB of RAM, you won't be able to allocate *all* of that (maybe not even most of it) to a guest OS.

Comment: 2gig ram it seems.

Comment: My laptop has 4GB RAM out of which i alloted 2GB to VMware

Comment: You need to try to allocate *less* RAM to the VM, not more. Trying to allocate more RAM makes it more likely that the allocation will fail.

Comment: I even tried to allocated as low as 512MB to it but still no luck :-(

Comment: @user256091 What other processes do you have running? Can you open the Task Manager (press Ctrl+Shift+Esc), and in the performance tab, look at the graph of memory and tell us how much memory your system is currently using?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to run VMWare workstation as an administrator.  Some Windows Updates have created this problem from time to time.  Follow the first recommendation in this article:  http://www.petri.com/fixing-enough-physical-memory-available-errors-vmware-workstation.htm

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please include the relevant information from the linked page in your post. If the link is ever broken, your answer will no longer be as useful.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with VMWare Player 4.0.6 on Win8.1/64 with 10GB of RAM, no visible application running, when trying to launch a 1GB Linux VM. Running as administrator helped, uninstalling KB2995388 didn't. I've not tried messing with config.ini.